# Why does react-table Column not accept a function as accessor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-table

I have encountered a small problem converting my app to typescript. Here is the (shortened) code:

I have a type with a simple string property:

```js
export type Person = {
     birth_date: string
...
```

This is used in a custom table component using `react-table`:

```js
import {useTable, useSortBy, Column} from 'react-table'

const PersonTable: FC<{persons: Person, columns: Column<Person>}> = ({ persons, columns }) => {

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
      useTable<Person>({ columns, data: persons }, useSortBy)
...
```

Because birth_date is formatted YYYY-MM-DD, I want to change it to something readable when defining the columns, where formatDate returns a string:

```js
const columnsPersons = useMemo(() => [
    {
        Header: 'Birth date',
        accessor: (row: Person) => formatDate(row.birth_date)
    }
], [])
```

But when I set

```js
<PersonTable columns={columnsPersons} ...
```

I get the following error (shortened):

```
Type '{ Header: string; accessor: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ accessor: "birth_date"; }'.
Types of property 'accessor' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"birth_date"'.
```

I know I can use a function for the accessor, because this works. But I don't know if I'm using and / or typing it correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you returned wider type from formatDate than the accessor expected. You should return from formatDate a 'birth_date' type, not string. Or describe the column like { 'what returned from formatDate': string } instead of { 'birth_date': string }

```
// 1.
const formatDate = (date) => return date as 'birth_date'

// 2. 
const formatDate = (date: string): 'another_birth_date' => { .... }

const PersonTable: FC<{persons: Person, columns: Column<{'another_birth_date': string}>
```

Comment: But `birth_date` is not a type. It is a property on the type `Person`. Both the type of `birth_date` and the type of `formatDate()` is string. So why does the typescript engine think it is a type?